# How to find min value of each col in df and delete previous values?

Tags: r, dataframe

Assuming I have the following data frame:

```
x1 <- c(12:4, 5:8, NA, NA)
x2 <- c(15:8, 9:15)
x3 <- c(14:9, 10:13, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)

df <- data.frame(x1, x2, x3)
```

How can I search for the minimum value in each column, delete all values before and fill the columns with NAs to preserve equal length? NAs should only be added to the end of the cols, so that the lowest values are in row Nr. 1. 
My real dfs have varying numbers of cols and rows.

The desired result is:

```
  x1  x2  x3
1  4   8   9 
2  5   9  10
. 
.
8 NA  15  NA
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming your "df" is actually:

```
df <- data.frame(x1, x2, x3)
```

In that case you can try something like:

```
data.frame(lapply(df, function(y) {
  y[1:which.min(y)] <- NA
  y
}))
#    x1 x2 x3
# 1  NA NA NA
# 2  NA NA NA
# 3  NA NA NA
# 4  NA NA NA
# 5  NA NA NA
# 6  NA NA NA
# 7  NA NA 10
# 8  NA NA 11
# 9  NA  9 12
# 10  5 10 13
# 11  6 11 NA
# 12  7 12 NA
# 13  8 13 NA
# 14 NA 14 NA
# 15 NA 15 NA
```

---

After reading your comment and edit, perhaps this is what you are looking for instead:

```
data.frame(lapply(df, function(y) {
  x1 <- rep(NA, nrow(df))
  x2 <- which.min(y):length(y)
  x1[seq_along(x2)] <- y[x2]
  x1
}))
#    x1 x2 x3
# 1   4  8  9
# 2   5  9 10
# 3   6 10 11
# 4   7 11 12
# 5   8 12 13
# 6  NA 13 NA
# 7  NA 14 NA
# 8  NA 15 NA
# 9  NA NA NA
# 10 NA NA NA
# 11 NA NA NA
# 12 NA NA NA
# 13 NA NA NA
# 14 NA NA NA
# 15 NA NA NA
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I think my question was not clear enough. I don't want to have NAs at the beginning of the cols.